# Making a "pressing" effect on a TextButton with a shadow

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm currently generating the font for my TextButton with a shadow, using FreeType. I would like to do something so that when I click on the textbutton, the text is moved a bit down and to the right, simulating a press. The shadow shouldn't move. Here's and example of what I mean:

[image: Example]

Notice how the shadow doesn't move. How can I accomplish something like this? I suspect it has something to do with drawables, but I'm not sure. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: You can make an animation, and when it clicks the button, you play the key frames you want!

Comment: But wouldn't that require me to have multiple fonts? Notice how the shadow doesn't move.

Comment: Then easier is to create two version of button and mark in the skin as up/down - I'm curious if it is possible to play with pure FreeType

Comment: Yes, this is what I have been thinking as well. I don't really feel like generating an image for each button, or something like that, it would affect performance too much. But it doesn't have to be purely FreeType.

Comment: There are many ways this could be done. One idea: make font unshadowed. Put two buttons in a Stack (bottom one disabled and with dark color). Adjust the padding of the buttons to control the offsets for the shadow and pressed button (the top button's padding changing while it's down). Second idea: make special font with the text offset differently in the RGB channels. Use special shader to choose which ones to draw. You would need to subclass TextButton to switch the sprite batch to your shader while it's drawing and then switch it back.

Comment: Third idea: Make a specialized font. Use alternate characters to represent pressed versions of the characters you need. For example, the symbol @ could be a 2 in the pressed state. Then you could change the text of the button to a different string while it's pressed. You would probably need to use a tool like ShoeBox to easily create a font like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. My idea is to override the **TextButton** class with the one that will handle touchingDown and touchingUp itself.

The class is creating two types of fonts (you will need the .ttf file but of course you can change it and pass BitmapFont objects or something) - and generally good idea is to choose thin and bold font (because of shadow).

Here is the code - I made comments with description how it works and what am I actually doing, because Ive found it more convenient:

```
    package put.here.your.package;


    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.LabelStyle;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;

    public class MyTextButton extends TextButton
    {
        BitmapFont upFont, downFont;
        LabelStyle upStyle, downStyle;
        float upLeftPad, upTopPad, downLeftPad, downTopPad;

        public MyTextButton(String text, Skin skin, String styleName) //you can create more constructors just call in them super then init!
        {
            super(text, skin, styleName);

            init();
        }

        private void init()
        {   
            //see the comments near the method below
            this.createFonts();

            //this is important! it will cleared effect of skin up/down settings what is good for me but should not be for you - then remove the following line
            this.clearListeners();

            //creating styles basing on current style and fonts we have generated
            upStyle = new LabelStyle( this.getLabel().getStyle() );
            upStyle.font = upFont;

            downStyle = new LabelStyle( this.getLabel().getStyle() );
            downStyle.font = downFont;

            //setting upStyle for a start - on a start the button is not pushed
            this.getLabel().setStyle(upStyle);

            //setting the listener that will change the style due to is button clicked or not right now - see its definition on the bottom of class
            this.addListener(clickListener);

            //this is calculating current 
            this.upLeftPad = getLabelCell().getPadLeft();
            this.upTopPad = getLabelCell().getPadTop();

            this.downLeftPad = getLabelCell().getPadLeft() + 4; //the value (4) should be changed if you will change shadowOffset of fonts
            this.downTopPad = getLabelCell().getPadTop() + 4; //because we want to make shadow small and move label which make us an illusion of pushing font

            //here one note! the funny thing is that imho above value should be shadowOffsetY of upFont - shadowOffsetY of downFont
            //but it is not actually - I mean it is not ok, right bottom corner is not at the same position which is weird so just choose your value
        }

        //this method create two fonts - up version and pushed version - the pushed version should have smaller shadow
        private void createFonts()
        {
            //firstly we need a generator (integrated with LibGDX) to generate from .ttf file - so you will need .ttf!
            FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font.ttf")); //path to yout .ttf file
            FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();

            parameter.size = 42;

            parameter.magFilter = TextureFilter.Linear; //it will make
            parameter.minFilter = TextureFilter.Linear; //the font render better

            //generating font for nonclicked (up) button version
            parameter.shadowOffsetX = 6; //defining of 
            parameter.shadowOffsetY = 6; //shadow offset ~= size

            upFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);

            //generating font for nonclicked (up) button version
            parameter.shadowOffsetX = 3; //as above
            parameter.shadowOffsetY = 3; //it should be smaller!

            downFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);

            //fonts are generated

            generator.dispose();
        }

        //setting style and label offset for pushed button
        private void setDown()
        {
            getLabel().setStyle(downStyle);

            getLabelCell().padTop( downTopPad );
            getLabelCell().padLeft( downLeftPad );
        }

        //setting style and label offset for non pushed button
        private void setUp()
        {
            getLabel().setStyle(upStyle);

            getLabelCell().padTop( upTopPad );
            getLabelCell().padLeft( upLeftPad );
        }

        //the listener that will change style due to what action is actually being performed on the button
        ClickListener clickListener = new ClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
                setDown();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)
            {
                setUp();
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
                setUp();
            }
        };

    }
```

and you are using it just like:

```
    MyTextButton start = new MyTextButton("START", game.skin, "button");
    stage.addActor(start);
```

---

Notes:

- You should change the package from first line to yours
- You can manipulate the MyTextButton settings changing shadow offsets and font offset **and you will have to when you will change font size** - for now it is 42
- You can change class name to TextButton and use it as simple TextButton (just import proper one)
- You are creating normal skin and the properties for **up** will be kept while properties for **down** will be ignored (however you can cancel ignoring **down** by deleting `clearListeners()` line )
- The class handle both **touchUp** and **touchDrag** situations (so if you click on the button then move mouse it will behave as when touchUp)
- You can add your own listeners of course to use the button to changing screens for example

The effect:

[image]